# Finding effect size for comparison of attributes

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statistics

Is there a way to find the sum of squares for each dependent variable in a dataset, which can then be used to compute the eta squared values

```
for d in districts:
    ss_b += district_dict[d].shape[0] * \
            np.sum((district_dict[d].mean() - data['total_score'].mean())**2)

ss_t = np.sum((data['total_score']-data['total_score'].mean())**2)        
eta_squared = ss_b/ss_t
```

Data Format

```
Store    SKU    type1    color_blue    color_black  RM_Leather  RM_syn   salerate
1        111    Shoe      1                 0          1          0         .3
1        221    Shoe      0                 1          1          0         .7
```

Sale rate is dependent and everything else is independent

I found this here : https://codingdisciple.com/hypothesis-testing-ANOVA-python.html

im trying to replicate this so i can use it on all my dependent variables(40+)

```
(Final.iloc[:,10:-2] - Final.SaleRate.mean()).apply(np.square).sum()
```

Is the above code valid to calculate the SSB's for each dependent variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```py
df.apply(np.square).sum()
```

Comment: `(df - df.mean()).apply(np.square).sum()` or even simpler : `(df.shape[0] - 1)* df.var()`

Comment: For ss_b, you can use : `(df - df.total_score.mean()).apply(np.square).sum()`

Comment: ```(Final.iloc[:,10:-2] - Final.SaleRate.mean()).apply(np.square).sum()``` as in my case SaleRate is the dependent var, this line is giving me a list of sum of squares for every independent variable.
Is this right?

Comment: Sorry, it's not possible to help you further wihtout details about your data

Comment: I think it should work. Calculate the f-statistics using these lines, and then try with [f_oneway](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f_oneway.html) and compare results

Comment: Very Large diff between above line and f_oneway, is the value assigned to each column name when i use: ```(Final.iloc[:,10:-2] - Final.SaleRate.mean()).apply(np.square).sum()``` the SSB for each column? would this divided by sum of ssb of all columns give the partail eta squared? Youre decreasing the denominators values(not considering SSW) but numerators remain the same, so while proportions might vary, directionally they will be the same(ranking)

Comment: Exactly! When I said with these lines, I meant, using them to commpute ssb and sst. The line you last mentioned is to calculate ssb for each column.

Comment: One last question then, how would i compute SST?
As a total of all the SSb's will do?

Comment: `len(df['total_score']) * df['total_score'].var(ddof=0)`

Comment: the SST is .9 while the Sum of SSB's is 90500. Is this possible?
Sale rate is continuous while all the dependent variables are filled with dummy variables.

Comment: You compare the sum of the empirical variance for each feature (0/1) with sales, looks like reasonnable figures to me

Comment: but isnt the eta squared value supposed to lie between o and 1 ie SSB/SST